# Is it possible to process a stripe form via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
<form class="blocked-form efocus" action="form_process.php?source=payment" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="fee" value="1795">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-amount=1795 data-description="Month-to-month Package">
    </script>
</form>
```

To process this, I'm using `form.ajaxSubmit` but since I'm not using a submit button such as:

`<input type="submit" name="submit" class="general-button" value="Save and Continue" />`

It won't process via AJAX. Is there a way to process `form_process.php?source=payment` when clicking on the external button provided by stripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the form submit manually by registering a click handler for the external button

```
$('my-button').click(function(){
    $('form.efocus').submit()
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. A little wrinkle I just noticed is that the `class="stripe-button"` is not where I want to call `.submit` the `class="stripe-button"` creates an overlay window with a credit card processing form. How can I target the button on the newly created DOM elements?

Comment: You need to use `$(document).on('click', '<button>', function(){...})` model to register the event ahndler for a dynamic element